# C# casting error when deserializing

Tags: c#, serialization, casting, binaryformatter

I am trying to deserialize a BinaryFormatter in a 32bit C# exceldna addin that is serialized in a 64bit C# application.

When I call BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream) the following exception is thrown:

```
[A]System.Tuple`3[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MyExcelAddin.MyPropertyNames],MyApplication.DataOutput] cannot be cast to 
[B]System.Tuple`3[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MyExcelAddin.MyPropertyNames],MyApplication.DataOutput]. 

Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. 

Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
```

The types A and B appear identical and originate from the same library.  Any clues to what is going wrong here?  Is this a 64bit / 32bit thing?

Comment: What version of Net are you using? I think you need to use a version of Net >= than the one it was built in.

Comment: I haven't seen this specific scenario, but frankly this is reason #271 not to use `BinaryFormatter`; is changing serializer an option going forward? or is it going to be massively disruptive to existing data to do that?

Comment: Everything is built using .net 4.5 (does mscorlib 4.0.0.0 mean .net 4.5?)

Comment: I would prefer to stick with BinaryFormatter as it is a lot quicker than plain XML, but open to suggestions.

Comment: Seems it was caused by having a class defined in the 32bit namespace that is referenced in the 64bit one. Not sure why but this fixed it.

Comment: @john_smith_lon Suggest you use a binary formatter, but not BinaryFormatter. If you have very simple data structures that are unlikely to change, you can just hand roll something with a BinaryWriter. If you have more complex structures or need to handle schema changes I recommend e.g. protobuf.net

Comment: @john_smith_lon I am having the exact same issue. How did you solve it exactly? What do you mean by "having a class defined in the 32bit namespace that is referenced in the 64bit one".   I am also using ExcelDna bw.
Thank you in advance for your help.